# How to select lists elements in a large list based on sub-elements inside every element list?

Tags: r, list

I have a large list that has many combinations of character variables from a data.frame. My goal is subset the combinations that have a character sub-element ("var_pib_nsa_interanual") inside every list element that have that, and delete others. In other words, I want delete lists elements that don't have an especific sub-element and keep that have.

I tried many alternatives, but any of them are good enough.

[An image of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3PKL.png)

I tried:

```
sapply(x, function(x) any(x[1] == "var_pib_nsa_interanual", na.rm = T))

lapply(x,"[","var_pib_nsa_interanual")
```

And others.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your list, ie a list of at least length 2, and inside elements also of at least length 2 etc.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the list you mentioned. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the base `Filter` function.

```
# example list
ex = list(
  "a",
  "var_pib_nsa_interanual",
  c('a', "var_pib_nsa_interanual"),
  "no"
)

Filter(\(x) "var_pib_nsa_interanual" %in% x, ex)
# [[1]]
# [1] "var_pib_nsa_interanual"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"                      "var_pib_nsa_interanual"
```

Comment: What does \\(x) means at this command ?

Comment: Since R version 4.0, `\(x)` is the same as `function(x)`. So I'm making an anonymous function that checks if `"var_pib_nsa_interanual"` is in a vector.

Comment: I did: Filter(function(x){"var_pib_nsa_interanual" %in% x}, 
                   combinacoes_possiveis[[i]])

Comment: Worked fine here !